# Como é testado o kernel Linux ou programas escritos em C?

Tags: c, linux, testes, kernel

Quando utilizamos linguagem Java, utilizamos o JUnit para testar os códigos. Mas os códigos escritos em C, como o *kernel* Linux, como é testado?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em tese pode-se usar qualquer metodologia de teste e qualquer ferramenta que ajude este processo em C pode ser usada.

Em Java você usa JUnit, outros programadores usam outra coisa.

Até onde eu sei o [Autotest](http://autotest.github.io/) é usado pela comunidade de desenvolvimento do Linux Kernel.

Pelas informações que eu li há iniciativas de testes independentes também, algumas bem organizadas, como o [Linux Test Project](http://linux-test-project.github.io/).

Além disto a comunidade é muito ativa e nem sempre é usada uma metodologia muito formal como ocorre em certos projetos.

Em alguns tipos de projetos por si só e pelo tipo de programador envolvido, os testes formais se tornam menos necessários. Não espere que tenha um grupo que responsabilidade formal de testar qualquer alteração enviada para o repositório. O Linux é um projeto que mostra que se dá mais ênfase aos testes do que deveria. Um projeto tão complexo e que tem reputação de qualidade se vira bem sem testes ostensivos.

Olhando por outro lado, alguns tipos de projeto sequer são adequados para testes de unidade.

Algumas ferramentas para testes de unidade em C:

- [AceUnit](http://aceunit.sourceforge.net/)
- [API Sanity Checker](http://lvc.github.io/api-sanity-checker/)
- [GNU Autounit](http://autounit.tigris.org/) (parece morto)
- [Automated Testing Framework](https://github.com/jmmv/atf)
- [Check](https://libcheck.github.io/check/)
- [CUnit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/)
- [CuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net/)
- [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/)
- [embUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/embunit/)
- [Google Test framework](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/)